# Flutter Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Invalid date format

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to format my date and time.

My code

```
    String dateStart = data[i]['notification_date'];
    DateTime input = DateTime.parse(dateStart);
    String datee = DateFormat('hh:mm a').format(input);
```

its showing error  Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Invalid date format

right now its look like this `22-04-2021 05:57:58 PM`

Comment: what is the 'a' in the format that doesn't seem correct

Answer (score 11):

You have an issue in following line:

```
DateTime input = DateTime.parse(dateStart);
```

Thing is that default parse method does not support '22-04-2021 05:57:58 PM' format, as it is not standard. You should specify its format to parse like this:

```dart
  String dateStart = '22-04-2021 05:57:58 PM';
  DateFormat inputFormat = DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a');
  DateTime input = inputFormat.parse(dateStart);
  String datee = DateFormat('hh:mm a').format(input);
```